# Mootools: Formcheck tips over lightbox

Tags: mootools, lightbox, z-index

I have a form on a lightbox, that form is server side validated with PHP (no issues there) and client side validated with formCheck for Mootools,
Is it possible to show the error messages on top of a lightbox?

By default it shows them under the lightbox, and therefore useless to the user filling the form, since they cannot be seen.

Any way of getting over this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fix the [z-index](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_pos_z-index.asp)'s?

Comment: I tried it, that's why it was one of the tags, but it still appears below the actual lightbox